# How can I strip all line breaks to generate a proper CSV?

Tags: php, csv

I have a textarea submitting to my database on a website that is properly working. But when I generate a CSV (via PHP) from my database, all line breaks will mess up with the resulting CSV. Any CSV reader will interpret the line break from the input into a new line.

I have tried the following approaches:

1. Encapsulating the fields in quotation marks.
2. This:

   ```
   $field = str_replace(array('\n', '\r', '\r\n', '\n\r'), ',', $original_field);
   ```
3. Also this:

   ```
   $field = strip_tags(nl2br($original_field));
   ```
4. Combining all approaches above.

Anyhow, the ending result will still be a messed up CSV that will break on any line break inputted by user. I have managed to block new line breaks from the text area, but there's a lot of legacy submissions that need me to fix this on the CSV side as well.

Why is it not working? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How are you creating your CSV?

Comment: Are your database entries already in CSV format?

Comment: No. I'm generating via fwrite. But after reading the replies I might rethink and generate via putcsv.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Before accepted answer (of user `user1517891`) is not correct, it will replace in string twice, when there is `\r\n`... It will replace it as two commas `,`. First it will replace `\r` => `,`, then `\n` => `,`.

You need to use it in different order, as:

```
$field = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\n", "\r"), ',', $original_field);
```

Answer (score 9):

Use double quotes:

```
$field = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\r\n", "\n\r"), ',', $original_field);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using `preg_replace()` for this rather than `str_replace()`. The reason is that there may be multiple newlines and combinations of `\r` and `\n`, and I would expect that you'd want to replace them all with just a single comma.

I'd also suggest using `trim()` to remove trailing blank lines.

```
$field = preg_replace('/[\n\r]+/', ',', trim($original_field));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `\n` and similar tags in double quotes otherwise they will be treated as simple strings and not as linebreaks.