# Editing values received from the database

Tags: php, database

Through PHP I downloaded an array with product descriptions from the database, but when adding them to the csv file, they contain unnecessary newlines. Is it possible to somehow remove them without interfering with the database (from the php level) ?

I tried to edit according to advice, but unfortunately it does not turn out as it should. I tried str_replace () but also to no avail:

````
            
            $file_open = fopen("file_empik.csv", "w");
            fputcsv($file_open, $heders);
            

            foreach($title_from_shopify_table as $info)       
            {
                $descr = $info['descr'];
                str_replace('\n', '', $descr);
                print_r($descr);

                $line_info = array('', $info['title'], $info['descr'], $info['sku'], $info['imgsrc'], '23%', $info['vendor']);
                
                fputcsv($file_open, $line_info);
                
            }
            fclose($file_open);
            
            return $products_data; ```

Thank you for any help
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158753/how-can-i-strip-all-line-breaks-to-generate-a-proper-csv/31726332

Answer (score 0):

You can stock it to variable, then you'll be able to edit what you want.

Something like

```
$array = callFromDatabase

foreach($array as $line) {
$line.editMethod // What you want to do ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex!

This replaces them with a space:

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string));
```

Here is more information on preg_replace:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_regex_preg_replace.asp

Edit: If you are simply wanting to store the data and mess around with it then you should use a variable as @Devinfo_dh has pointed out.